# created a hash and when using length function it is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

Following is code to generate a hash and now I am trying to iterate over hash but no luck

```js
let intArr = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]
let cntArr = {};

for (let index in intArr) {
  cntArr[intArr[index]] = intArr[index] + 1
}
console.log(cntArr);
console.log(cntArr.length) // undefined

for(let [key, value] in Object.entries(cntArr))
{
 console.log(value+' '+key);  //undefined 0 ????
}
```

cntArr is type object and I am puzzled that why I can't get iterate hash.. what can I be missing.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: To solve ```for(let [key, value] in Object.entries(cntArr))
{
 console.log(value+' '+key);  //undefined 0 ????
}``` change "for in" to "for of"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects don't have a `length` property - you can use `forEach` over `Object.keys` if you want to iterate over the object:

```js
let intArr = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]
let cntArr = {};

for (let index in intArr) {
  cntArr[intArr[index]] = intArr[index] + 1
}
console.log(cntArr);
console.log("Length of cntArr: ", Object.keys(cntArr).length);
Object.keys(cntArr).forEach(key => console.log(key, cntArr[key]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you wish to iterate through both the key and value of an object:

```js
let intArr = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]
let cntArr = {};

for (let index in intArr) {
  cntArr[intArr[index]] = intArr[index] + 1
}
console.log(cntArr);
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(cntArr)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: when I am trying to iterate object let [key,value] in cntArr I get key but values are undefined ...any clue? I updated the code

Comment: Try using `let [key, value] in Object.entries(cntArr)`.

Comment: undefined 0, undefined 1,undefined 2----> key array is not correct now

Comment: I'll fix that, sorry @user269867.

Comment: Fixed @user269867 - if you want to use `Object.entries` you need `for...of`. See my code now.

Answer (score 2):

An javascript object doesn't have a `length` property unless you give it one. If you want to know how many keys are in the object  you can look at the length of the array returned from [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
let intArr = [2,2,3,4,4,3,3]
let cntArr={};

for(let index in intArr){
    cntArr[intArr[index]] = intArr[index] + 1

}
console.log(Object.keys(cntArr).length)

// all keys:

console.log(...Object.keys(cntArr))
```

Can also iterate over `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.entries` if you want to step through all the items in the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for loop to iterate through a hash, also you can use `Object.keys(cntArr).length` to determine the length of your hash object

```js
let intArr = [2,2,3,4,4,3,3]
let cntArr={};

for(let index in intArr){
    cntArr[intArr[index]] = intArr[index] + 1
}
console.log(cntArr);
console.log('hash size: ' + Object.keys(cntArr).length)
 
for(var i in cntArr){
 console.log(i);
}
```